# error when trying to use click() to interact with a website using tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

HTML code that I am interacting with

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);

function checkKeyPressed(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 83) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("btn-standard section-header-btn mini call-to-action")[1].click();
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-standard section-header-btn mini call-to-action" style="">Re-list All</button>
```

Error:

```
    Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.checkKeyPressed
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is the `[1]` on your `document.getElementsByClassName`. You are telling your code to get the second instance of this button. Remember that coding starts at 0. Try the following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn-standard section-header-btn mini call-to-action")[0].click();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I believe that I am trying to get the second instant of this button. Furthermore, when I try to interact with the first button it does not work either. thank you for your help though!

Comment: Are you able to add an ID and target it that way?

Comment: I was able to do that and I used document.getElementById("myid").click() but it is as if it ignores the command. no error this time. Thanks though.

Comment: actually with some experimentation when I console.log(document.getElementById("myid")) it displays only the html code where it is found. I am new to html code so I may have made a mistake. I only added id = "myid" before style.